# How to run a function inside of script tag after browser closing?

Tags: javascript, event-handling

I am running the below script inside of index.html to run the Genesys Web Messenger widget. Genesys has its own JS SDK that I am using with success within the . I listen for an event inside the widget and then run a command which works.

However, I would like to handle the case when a user closes the tab/browser and based on that action (beforeunload) run the function I created to clear the conversation.

It does run the function as I get a log to the console, but the conversation is not cleared.

Please advise if I am using the Listener correct or if it will work inside of the Genesys script, etc..

I tried running the Event Listener in several different configuration as well as using unload.

```html
<script>
    (function(g, e, n, es, ys) {
        g['_genesysJs'] = e;

        g[e] = g[e] || function() {
            (g[e].q = g[e].q || []).push(arguments)
        };

        g[e].t = 1 * new Date();

        g[e].c = es;

        ys = document.createElement('script');
        ys.async = 1;
        ys.src = n;
        ys.charset = 'utf-8';
        document.head.appendChild(ys);

    })(window, 'Genesys', '<https://apps.mypurecloud.com/genesys-bootstrap/genesys.min.js>', {
        environment: 'xxxxxx',
        deploymentId: 'xxxxxxxx'
    });

    Genesys("subscribe", "MessagingService.conversationDisconnected", function({
        data
    }) {
        console.log(data);
        Genesys("command", "MessagingService.clearConversation")
    });

    Genesys("subscribe", "MessagingService.restored", function({
        data
    }) {
        console.log(data);
        Genesys("command", "MessagingService.clearConversation")
    });

    function releaseConv() {
        console.log("data");
        Genesys("command", "MessagingService.clearConversation");
    }
    window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function(event) {
        releaseConv();
        event.preventDefault();
        event.returnValue = '';
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can't run anything after the page closes. You can use the `unload` and `beforeunload` methods to run code when it's closing.